# Controller class not found for Symfony 3 route

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting the error

```
`The _controller value "AppBundle:GasSupplier:overview" maps to a
"AppBundle\Controller\GasSupplierController" class, but this class was not found. Create
this class or check the spelling of the class and its namespace.`
```

But as far as I can tell, the class does exist, with the correct namespace, in the correct directory. My app/config/routing.yaml is

```
AppBundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

and the contents of my src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml is

```
homepage:
  path: /
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }

gassupplieroverview:
  path: /gassuppliers
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:GasSupplier:overview }
```

and the contents of my src/AppBundle/Controller/GasSupplier.php is

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class GasSupplierController extends Controller
{
    public function overviewAction(Request $request)
    {
        $gas_suppliers = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:GasSupplier')->findAll();

        return $this->render('gas_supplier/overview.html.twig', ['gas_suppliers' => $gas_suppliers]);
    }
}
```

All the other answers I have found about this, the answer was almost always a typo  - I have checked and checked again and I don't think I have any typos...

Using Symfony 3.

Comment: The file should be named `src/AppBundle/Controller/GasSupplierController.php`

Comment: @Matteo That was it. Thanks. Can't believe I still missed that...

Comment: Hi @Kvothe you are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo: GasSupplierController in the class name, vs GasSupplier.php as the filename.

Wherever it says `GasSupplier` (including the filename), should be renamed/changed-to `GasSupplierController`, to match the class name.

Comment: That was it, can't believe I still missed that. Thanks. I'm now having problems getting the routes to work if I use localhost running from Wamp (everything works fine when using the built in server with symfony) but I guess that's a separate question.